# Angular 5 обработка данных

Tags: json, angular5

Я пишу фронтенд на Angular. Мне приходит данные такие как:
JSON(1):

```
{
   'department':{
       {'departmentId':1,
       'name':'IS'},
       {'departmentId':2,
       'name':'MKM'}
   }

}
```

JSON(2):

```
 {
   'speciality':{
       'specialityId':1,
       'name':'Information System',
       'departmentId':'1'
   }
}
```

Таких связей у меня много, и мне надо всегда как нибудь проверять и выводить данные speciality(Например) и связанные с ним данные(department).У некоторых таких связей нет.
Когда вывожу данные speciality для изменения, вместо departmentId должно выводить `<select><option>..`
Можете подкинуть идеи для решение этой задачи?

Comment: У вас какой-то не валидный `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Пример на [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-start-otus-wdddkl?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Пример кода для связывания данных:

Код компонента:

```
export class AppComponent {
  departments = [
       {'departmentId':1,
       'name':'IS'},
       {'departmentId':2,
       'name':'MKM'}
  ];
  speciality = {
       'specialityId':1,
       'name':'Information System',
       'departmentId':'1'
   }
}
```

HTML код компонента:

```
<div>id : {{speciality.specialityId}}</div>
<div>name : {{speciality.name}}</div>
<div>departmentId : {{speciality.departmentId}}</div>
<select [(ngModel)]="speciality.departmentId">
  <option *ngFor="let item of departments" [value]="item.departmentId">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```